# Cannot import Python Dependencies in Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, conda

I am following this instruction from [databricks](https://databricks.com/blog/2020/12/22/how-to-manage-python-dependencies-in-pyspark.html) to run use some libraries in the distributed environment but I still have errors when using `jupyter` notebook with `conda` (in Standalone mode).

The example code:

```py
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf

@pandas_udf('double')
def pandas_plus_one(v: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    return v + 1

spark.range(10).select(pandas_plus_one("id")).show()
```

I use these commands to create `conda` environment:

```sh
conda create -y -n pyspark_conda_env -c conda-forge pyarrow pandas conda-pack
conda activate pyspark_conda_env
conda pack -f -o pyspark_conda_env.tar.gz
```

And I got this error:

```
ImportError: PyArrow >= 0.15.1 must be installed; however, it was not found.
```

So I uninstall `pyarrow` and install it with `pip install pyarrow` to get the latest version.

But I still got that error.

I even use this code in the notebook but it doesn't work either:

```py
import os
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = "./environment/bin/python"
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(
    "spark.archives",  # 'spark.yarn.dist.archives' in YARN.
    "pyspark_conda_env.tar.gz#environment").getOrCreate()
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Do you know what version of `PyArrow` are you installing?

Comment: @FourBars With `pip` is `6.0.0`. Create with `conda` is `0.11.1`